# Overflow icon in action bar invisible

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I am creating action bar in my code using support library. Then I am creating overflow icon in action bar in my code. When I run my app its show overflow icon but when I run my device its invisible. From some links I found reason behind this is presence of menu `button` on my device. Is it true? And how to show overflow icon on each device?

Code-

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
     <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_1"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        yourapp:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/share"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_2"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        yourapp:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/contact"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_3"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        yourapp:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/contact1"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: Set `showAsAction` as `android:showAsAction="always"`. Your item that inflates your overflow menu MUST showAsAction="always

Comment: But I dont want to make above items visible in action bar. I want these items in overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make your **menu.xml** like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- Search / will display always -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_search"/>
<!-- Overflow More -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/a_More"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="More">

    <menu>

 <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_1"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    yourapp:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/share"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_2"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    yourapp:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/contact"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_3"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    yourapp:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/contact1"/>
    </menu>
</item>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, if your device is having a menu button, the overflow icon will not be shown.

You can use this workaround. Irrespective of which device you're using, the icon is shown always. However, it is **not recommended** to be used. Leave it the way it is done by default.

```
try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if(menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Ignore
    }
```

Comment: Preferably at the end of the `onCreate` method

Comment: This code works with android support library and on all devices?

Comment: On API levels below 11 still overflow icon is not visible.